# Автообновление ленты новостей

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь написать ленту новостей, которая сама обновляется каждые N-минут. 
Посещение сайта примерно 2000-3000 тыч уников. 
Не ляжет ли сервер от этого? И как нужно оптимизировать?

Comment: пытаюсь проехать 4000км, не подскажете не сломается ли мое транспортное средство и что нужно подкрутить чтобы не сломалось ? Смогу ли я ехать быстрее ?

Comment: согласен! глупый вопрос!) но хоть примерно посоветуйте.. че и как )

Comment: не глупый а не о чем,тут нечего советовать, кроме как вопрос придумать получше.

Comment: но вы же поняли, о чем я...

Comment: нет, не понял, правда, это невозможно понять. есть какой-то сайт с чем-то неизвестным у него там 2000-3000 уникальных посещений. и на нем ещё лента новостей, обновляется каждые N-минут, ещё стоят тэги jquery, ajax, что вообще сбивает с толку.

Comment: ну ладно... что поделаешь

Comment: А как у вас обновление устроено? какая БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь реализацией как в VK. Отобразите последние 10 записей из ленты, остальное подгружайте, урезая тем самым запрос к базе. Вытяните скажем 100 последних ID записей и затем подгружайте 10 из 100 отсекая уже выведенные записи, это даст прирост в производительности.

Answer (score 0):

за N-минут сервер не ляжет. Плюс - на хостингах как правило происходит кэширование. Поэтому нет смысла беспокоится.